# ISO-8859-1 Not working on IE

Tags: python, html, utf-8, iso-8859-1

I am working on some programs in spanish, so I need to use accent marks. This is why I use 
 `# -*- coding: iso-8859-1 -*-` and `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">` on all my programs (python). I tested in chrome,firefox and safari and they all work puttin the accent marks. The only one that does not work is IE8. It does not apply the accent mark, and add some other character instead.

Does anyone know if there is a problem with IE8?

Is it better to use UTF-8 instead?

Comment: Does your HTTP server add a `Content-Encoding` header?

Comment: "Is it better to use UTF-8 instead?" – Generally, yes.

Comment: Are your code files ASNI or Unicode?

Comment: @rcdmk: The post already states that the source files are encoded in ISO-8859-1.

Comment: @SvenMarnach I already change the charset to UTF-8 but it wont accept any accent mark or 'ñ'. It was better when I have it with the ISO-8859-1. Maybe I am misunderstanding how to change it.

Comment: You still didn't tell us if there is a `Content-Encoding`.  This header might contradict the embedded `meta` tag, and different browsers might resolve this contradiction differently.  If you get everything right, both ISO-8859-1 and UTF-8 should work, but UTF-8 is preferred.

Comment: @SvenMarnach Do you refer to "# -*- coding: iso-8859-1 -*-"? I have that on the header. I change that # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

Comment: No, I'm referring to what your HTTP server transfers to the client in the `Content-Encoding` HTTP header, not to the source file encoding of your Python files.  (Note that changing the source code encoding requires not only to change the encoding tag, but also to actually recode the source file.)

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance, but how can I verify the Content-Encoding? @SvenMarnach

Comment: Depends on your browser.  In case you are on a decent machine with `wget` installed, you can use `wget -S http://your.address.here/` to have the response headers printed.  (Also watch out for a `Content-Type` header.)

Comment: @SvenMarnach If there is not a Content-Encoding how do I add it?

Comment: Depends on your Webserver and/or the web framework you are using.  It shouldn't be too much of a problem if there is non such header, though, since then it cannot override your `meta` tag.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I 've learned a lot. I will try to fix it tomorrow

Comment: @mauguerra: It doesn't directly answer your question, but yesterday's article on Raymond Chen's blog, [What's the difference between Text Document, Text Document - MS-DOS Format, and Unicode Text Document?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2012/02/20/10269537.aspx) provides some useful background information and links to more resources for learning about this.  Other required reading: Joel Spolsky's [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is better to use UTF-8 instead.

Your question really cannot be answered unless you also provide the bytes that you are sending.

Comment: I just read that I need to use UTF-8 whenever I am working with AJAX, do you think is true?

Comment: @mauguerra: if you control the server, you can use whatever encoding you want with AJAX requests, but it's generally a bad idea to use non-unicode encodings at all IMO.

Comment: @mauguerra: According to [RFC 4627](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt), "JSON text SHALL be encoded in Unicode.  The default encoding is UTF-8."  As [RFC 2119](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2119.txt) points out, the word "SHALL" means that the corresponding statement is "an absolute requirement of the specification."  So if you're using JSON, to be standards-compliant, you must be using either UTF-8 or some other Unicode encoding.  For JSON data, UTF-8 is simpler and more compact so it should be preferred.

Answer (score 4):

It is better to use UTF-8.

Note that "iso-8859-1" is a common mislabeling of "windows-1252", also known as "cp1252". Try being more explicit and see if this resolves your issues.